# Understanding android app crash log output

Tags: java, android, debugging, crash-dumps

An android app just crashed and in the logs I see the following dump:

```
I/DEBUG   ( 1799): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
I/DEBUG   ( 1799): Build fingerprint: 'archos/G9A80/A80:3.2/HTJ85B/20111021.103312:user/release-keys'
I/DEBUG   ( 1799): pid: 3226, tid: 3228  >>> com.EXAMPLE.android.MYAPP <<<
I/DEBUG   ( 1799): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr deadbaad
I/DEBUG   ( 1799):  r0 deadbaad  r1 00000001  r2 a0000000  r3 00000000
I/DEBUG   ( 1799):  r4 00000000  r5 00000027  r6 4083a010  r7 00000063
I/DEBUG   ( 1799):  r8 4083a018  r9 0000000f  10 5854db2c  fp 5854ddbc
I/DEBUG   ( 1799):  ip ffffffff  sp 5854dae8  lr aff1929d  pc aff15a0c  cpsr 60000130
I/DEBUG   ( 1799):  d0  0000000000000000  d1  0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   ( 1799):  d2  0000000000000000  d3  0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   ( 1799):  d4  0000000000000000  d5  0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   ( 1799):  d6  0000000000000000  d7  0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   ( 1799):  d8  0000000000000000  d9  0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   ( 1799):  d10 0000000000000000  d11 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   ( 1799):  d12 0000000000000000  d13 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   ( 1799):  d14 0000000000000000  d15 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   ( 1799):  d16 0000000000000001  d17 3ff0000000000000
I/DEBUG   ( 1799):  d18 4146605000000000  d19 3fbc71c71c71c71c
I/DEBUG   ( 1799):  d20 4008000000000000  d21 3fd99a27ad32ddf5
I/DEBUG   ( 1799):  d22 3fd24998d6307188  d23 3fcc7288e957b53b
I/DEBUG   ( 1799):  d24 3fc74721cad6b0ed  d25 3fc39a09d078c69f
I/DEBUG   ( 1799):  d26 0000000000000000  d27 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   ( 1799):  d28 0000000000000000  d29 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   ( 1799):  d30 0000000000000000  d31 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   ( 1799):  scr 80000012
I/DEBUG   ( 1799): 
I/DEBUG   ( 1799):          #00  pc 00015a0c  /system/lib/libc.so
I/DEBUG   ( 1799):          #01  pc 00007322  /system/lib/libcutils.so (mspace_free)
I/DEBUG   ( 1799):          #02  pc 00068746  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmHeapSourceFreeList)
I/DEBUG   ( 1799):          #03  pc 0002e3b4  /system/lib/libdvm.so
I/DEBUG   ( 1799):          #04  pc 00019e24  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmHeapBitmapSweepWalk)
I/DEBUG   ( 1799):          #05  pc 0002e318  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmHeapSweepUnmarkedObjects)
I/DEBUG   ( 1799):          #06  pc 0001a4b0  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCollectGarbageInternal)
I/DEBUG   ( 1799):          #07  pc 00068b8c  /system/lib/libdvm.so
I/DEBUG   ( 1799):          #08  pc 0004be6a  /system/lib/libdvm.so
I/DEBUG   ( 1799):          #09  pc 00011770  /system/lib/libc.so (__thread_entry)
I/DEBUG   ( 1799):          #10  pc 000112c4  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_create)
I/DEBUG   ( 1799): 
I/DEBUG   ( 1799): libc base address: aff00000
I/DEBUG   ( 1799): 
I/DEBUG   ( 1799): code around pc:
I/DEBUG   ( 1799): aff159ec 4623b15c 2c006824 e026d1fb b12368db 
I/DEBUG   ( 1799): aff159fc 21014a17 6011447a 48124798 24002527 
I/DEBUG   ( 1799): aff15a0c f7f57005 2106ec92 ed20f7f6 460aa901 
I/DEBUG   ( 1799): aff15a1c f04f2006 94015380 94029303 e8eaf7f6 
I/DEBUG   ( 1799): aff15a2c 4622a905 f7f62002 f7f5e8f4 2106ec7e 

I/DEBUG   ( 1799): code around lr:
I/DEBUG   ( 1799): aff1927c 41f0e92d 46804c0c 447c2600 68a56824 
I/DEBUG   ( 1799): aff1928c e0076867 300cf9b5 dd022b00 47c04628 
I/DEBUG   ( 1799): aff1929c 35544306 37fff117 6824d5f4 d1ee2c00 
I/DEBUG   ( 1799): aff192ac e8bd4630 bf0081f0 0002823e 41f0e92d 
I/DEBUG   ( 1799): aff192bc fb01b086 9004f602 461f4815 4615460c 
I/DEBUG   ( 1799): 
I/DEBUG   ( 1799): stack:
I/DEBUG   ( 1799):     5854daa8  00000000  
I/DEBUG   ( 1799):     5854daac  00000000  
I/DEBUG   ( 1799):     5854dab0  00000000  
I/DEBUG   ( 1799):     5854dab4  00000000  
I/DEBUG   ( 1799):     5854dab8  aff416f8  
I/DEBUG   ( 1799):     5854dabc  aff41690  
I/DEBUG   ( 1799):     5854dac0  00000000  
I/DEBUG   ( 1799):     5854dac4  aff1929d  /system/lib/libc.so
I/DEBUG   ( 1799):     5854dac8  00000000  
I/DEBUG   ( 1799):     5854dacc  5854dafc  
I/DEBUG   ( 1799):     5854dad0  4083a010  
I/DEBUG   ( 1799):     5854dad4  00000063  
I/DEBUG   ( 1799):     5854dad8  4083a018  
I/DEBUG   ( 1799):     5854dadc  aff18409  /system/lib/libc.so
I/DEBUG   ( 1799):     5854dae0  df002777  
I/DEBUG   ( 1799):     5854dae4  e3a070ad  
I/DEBUG   ( 1799): #00 5854dae8  00000000  
I/DEBUG   ( 1799):     5854daec  00000001  
I/DEBUG   ( 1799):     5854daf0  4083a018  
I/DEBUG   ( 1799):     5854daf4  00000018  
I/DEBUG   ( 1799):     5854daf8  4083cf70  
I/DEBUG   ( 1799):     5854dafc  fffffbdf  
I/DEBUG   ( 1799):     5854db00  4083a018  
I/DEBUG   ( 1799):     5854db04  00000020  
I/DEBUG   ( 1799):     5854db08  00000000  
I/DEBUG   ( 1799):     5854db0c  afb07325  /system/lib/libcutils.so
I/DEBUG   ( 1799): #01 5854db10  40009288  
I/DEBUG   ( 1799):     5854db14  40d661d0  
I/DEBUG   ( 1799):     5854db18  5854dba4  
I/DEBUG   ( 1799):     5854db1c  00000063  
I/DEBUG   ( 1799):     5854db20  4083a018  
I/DEBUG   ( 1799):     5854db24  aca68749  /system/lib/libdvm.so

I/BootReceiver( 1905): Copying /data/tombstones/tombstone_03 to DropBox (SYSTEM_TOMBSTONE)
E/InputDispatcher( 1905): channel '40aae020 com.EXAMPLE.android.MYAPP /com.EXAMPLE.android.MYAPP .ACTIVITY (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x8
E/InputDispatcher( 1905): channel '40aae020 com.EXAMPLE.android.MYAPP /com.EXAMPLE.android.MYAPP .ACTIVITY (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
I/ActivityManager( 1905): Process com.EXAMPLE.android.MYAPP (pid 3226) has died.
I/WindowManager( 1905): WINDOW DIED Window{40aae020 com.EXAMPLE.android.MYAPP /com.EXAMPLE.android.MYAPP .ACTIVITY paused=false}
W/ActivityManager( 1905): Scheduling restart of crashed service com.EXAMPLE.android.MYAPP /com.EXAMPLE.android.framework.MYCLASS in 5000ms
W/WindowManager( 1905): Force-removing child win Window{411bf8f8 SurfaceView paused=false} from container Window{40aae020 com.EXAMPLE.android.MYAPP /com.EXAMPLE.android.MYAPP .ACTIVITY paused=false}
D/Zygote  ( 1801): Process 3226 terminated by signal (11)
```

There is some mention of "Scheduling restart of crashed service" towards the end but I'll need abit more than that to start debugging.

Any ideas?

Comment: First lines look like a dump of the CPU registers. I'm not familiar with ARM architecture. Maybe someone could confirm it.

Comment: Yeah, check out register 0 "deadbaad". Yes very baad.